# Up-to-date Retlang examples

Tags: .net, retlang

All Retlang examples/tutorials I can find on the web seem to be quite old: e.g.

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/11/01/Retlang--Concurrency-Library-for-C.aspx

http://www.colourcoding.net/blog/archive/2010/05/28/tweaking-the-retlang-queue-channel.aspx

There are, of course, [the tests](http://code.google.com/p/retlang/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/src/RetlangTests). Anything else?